# Append a existing div in angularjs and incrementing its id

Tags: angularjs

i am new to angularjs and i have one question, how can we append a existing div and also increment its id by using ng-click. Look at the below code for example

`<div id="item1">
  <p>This is Item1</p>
  <button>Click to Append</buton>
</div>`

When i click on the button another div should come with id item2 and the paragraph should say This is Item2.

Please help me out on this one,
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

inside your controller, put in a list of values

```
$scope.listOfDivs = [{id : 1, text: "Item1"}];
```

Now in your script, put this in:

```
<div ng-repeat="div in listOfDivs" id="{{"item" + div.id}}">
    <p>This is {{div.text}}</p>
    <button ng-click="listOfDivs.push({id: listOfDivs.length + 2, text: "Item" + (listOfDivs.length + 2)})">Click to Add new div</button>
</div>
```